# How to get data from database given range of date and time

Tags: sql, database

There is a database which has  data stored on it based on date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss). However I need data based on range of date and time. For eg. I need data from 03/11/15 to 03/18/15 only during time 15:00 to 18:00. How can I do this? Do I need to use nested sql queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing the values as strings.  If so, you can do something like:

```
where left(datecol, 10) between '2015-03-15' and '2015-03-18' and
      substr(datecol, 12, 2) between '15' and '17'
```

If you are storing this using native types (which is recommended), then you can do:

```
where (datecol >= '2015-03-15' and datecol < '2015-03-19') and
      hour(datecol) between 15 and 17
```

Note: these are schematics on what to do.  Different databases might have different ways of implementing the same functionality, such as `substring()` for `substr()` and `extract(hour from datecol)` for `hour()`.